# Article in Portuguese, how to get sentence case in bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, biber, babel, languages, apa-style

I'm writing an article in Portuguese, but where most references have English titles. I'm following the APA citation style. In the bibliography, I'd like to have terms like 'translator', date formats and ordinals in Portuguese, but sentence case capitalization according to the APA rules.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,main=portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@article{en,
author={John},
title={This Should Be in Sentence Case},
journal={Title Case Journal},
language={english}
}

@article{pt,
author={João},
title={Título do Artigo},
journal={Título da Publicação},
language={portuguese}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{en}
\nocite{pt}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

If I remove the `babel` package the article titles are correctly converted to sentence case. But how can I keep the localization features for Portuguese, as well as correct capitalization, at least for English language titles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `biblatex` `language` field is meant set "the language(s) of the work", and may be consumed by the entry type driver as content. What you are looking for is the  `langid` field, which tells `biblatex` the language in which the bib entry should be typeset.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,main=portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@article{en,
author={John},
title={This Should Be in Sentence Case},
journal={Title Case Journal},
langid={english}
}

@article{pt,
author={João},
title={Título do Artigo},
journal={Título da Publicação},
langid={portuguese}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{en}
\nocite{pt}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think only this change is likely sufficient. But you may be interested in the `autolang` option, which allows you to control which type of language environment is used by your bibliography entries.

Comment: Thank you! `langid` is indeed the correct field. The only things missing are: sentence case conversion for Portuguese; and assuming an english langid by default. Meanwhile I think I got these sorted out too (see my other answer).

Comment: I hadn't understood you wanted sentence case for Portuguese too. But I see you found your way around in the meantime. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 2):

I think I have this solved as far as I can tell right now. I needed to use the `langid` field as noted by @gusbrs. I also added sentence case conversion for bibliography entries in Portuguese. Since most of the entries on my bib file are in English and don't have a `langid`, and because the main language of the article is not English, I also added some code to add a default `langid` to entries that don't have one.

Here's the updated example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,main=portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@article{en,
author={John},
title={This Should Be in Sentence Case},
journal={Title Case Journal},
translator={Fulano},
}

@article{pt,
author={João},
title={Título do Artigo},
journal={Título da Publicação},
langid={portuguese}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=langid, fieldvalue={english}]
    }
  }
}

\AtBeginDocument[biblatex/declarecaselangs]{ %needed because of a bug in biblatex; maybe fixed soon...
  \DeclareCaseLangs*{portuguese}
}
\DeclareHookRule{begindocument}{biblatex/declarecaselangs}{after}{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\nocite{en}
\nocite{pt}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```